# React uploading - incorrect properties are passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to pass properties to component and in which to upload file for right user.
Here is sandbox example:

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-moon-mj5w6n?file=/src/Main.tsx
```

As you can see I have dummy data:

```
export default [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "John Doe",
    avatar: "app.png"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Anna Doe",
    avatar: "pic.png"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Michael Doe",
    avatar: "mypic.png"
  }
];
```

In my Main component I load CustomDataGrid component in which I am passing in one of its columns UploadAvatar component:

```
{
    field: "avatar",
    headerName: "Аватар",
    headerClassName: "home-header",
    editable: false,
    align: "center",
    headerAlign: "center",
    renderCell: (params) => (
      <UploadAvatar
        avatar={params.value}
        name={params.row.name}
        userId={params.row.id}
      />
    )
  },
```

The problem is the following as you can test:

**1.** Click avatar of the third Person Michael Doe
The console.log from this row:

```
    onClick={() => {
            console.log(userId);
            document.getElementById("avatar-input")!.click();
          }}
```

Gives correct passed parameters:
**mypic.png Michael Doe 3**

**2.** After choosing file, the console.log() from uploadAvatar function:

```
const uploadAvatar = (e: any) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (!file) return;
    console.log(avatar, name, userId);
  };
```

Gives parameters:

> app.png John Doe 1

Which are parameters the first user of the list, not the passed one. This is very strange for me and why I am having exactly the parameters I want in first console.log but suddenly when go in my uploadAvatar function I have different? How can I fix this behavior?

EDIT 1:

I am pasting Upload Component as you wanted:

```
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";

const UploadAvatar = ({
  avatar,
  name,
  userId
}: {
  avatar: string;
  name: string;
  userId: string;
}) => {
  const uploadAvatar = (e: any) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (!file) return;
    console.log(avatar, name, userId);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {avatar ? (
        <Avatar
          role="button"
          tabIndex={0}
          sx={{
            marginLeft: "-10px",
            marginRight: "10px",
            "&:hover": { cursor: "pointer" }
          }}
          alt="avatar"
          //src={`${shareServer}/avatars/${avatar}`}
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(avatar, name, userId);
            document.getElementById("avatar-input")!.click();
          }}
        ></Avatar>
      ) : (
        <Avatar
          role="button"
          tabIndex={0}
          sx={{
            marginLeft: "-10px",
            marginRight: "10px",
            "&:hover": { cursor: "pointer" }
          }}
          alt="avatar"
          src=""
          onClick={() => {
            document.getElementById("avatar-input")!.click();
          }}
        >
          {name
            ? name
                .split(/\s/)
                .reduce(
                  (response: any, word: any) => (response += word.slice(0, 1)),
                  ""
                )
            : ""}
        </Avatar>
      )}
      <input
        id="avatar-input"
        type="file"
        onChange={uploadAvatar}
        style={{ display: "none", position: "absolute" }}
        accept="image/*"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadAvatar;
```

Comment: can you share upload avatar component?

Comment: it is in the provided link in components folder

Comment: I think what you're missing is key prop. when you click on the component react all the components have same key i.e first components. that it is why it always selects first component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set unique id for file input:

```
      <input
        id={name}
        type="file"
        onChange={uploadAvatar}
        style={{ display: "none", position: "absolute" }}
        accept="image/*"
      />
```

```
        <Avatar
          role="button"
          tabIndex={0}
          sx={{
            marginLeft: "-10px",
            marginRight: "10px",
            "&:hover": { cursor: "pointer" }
          }}
          alt="avatar"
          //src={`${shareServer}/avatars/${avatar}`}
          onClick={() => {
            document.getElementById(name).click();
          }}
        />
```

And use ref for access DOM elements.

NOT:

```
document.getElementById(name).click();
```

With refs:

```
ref = useRef()

//...

     <input
        ref={ref}
        id={name}
        type="file"
        onChange={uploadAvatar}
        style={{ display: "none", position: "absolute" }}
        accept="image/*"
      />

//...

ref.current.click()
```

With ref wouldn't be a problem with not unique id.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-williamson-eqx82b?file=/src/component/UploadAvatar.tsx